# Waterlock, Sails, Angular JWT token gives 403 from browser

Tags: angularjs, sails.js, waterlock

backend: Sails app w/ Waterlock, Waterlock-local-auth
frontend: An angular app

I'm running into a issue where postman works fine, gets JWT from /user/jwt all good and dandy but whenever I login through the browser and then attempt to hit /user/jwt it gives 403 forbidden.  Any clues?

I have CORs enabled for all origins on all routes.

Any help would be appriciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save some time for novices like me:

$http won't be passing the session data with the request, so Sails/express server doesn't know which 'session' the /user/jwt request is being made from and hence giving 403, as it should. I guess Postman handles this for you automagically.

Added this to my angular config:

```
config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
}]).
```